# Json Object in development? Is it decided in front-end or back-end?

Tags: json, frontend, backend, web-frontend

I am working on web-app where layout are getting generated after getting JSON from backend. But the object recieved from backend is quite complicated and it requires to loop around the object quite a few times to get the layout.

And same is happening while Posting data to backend.

What I feel is that if we follow the front end layout to generate JSON Object to Post data and even if the object structure from backend will be changed, the layout generation will not need those extra loops.

So is the json Object always what backend gives or it should be according to front-end?

for example backend is giving

```
[
  {
    "keyid": "value",
    "attr1": "value1",
    "attr2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "keyid": "value",
    "attr3": "value3",
    "attr4": "value4"
  }
]
```

but it would be easy for front end to receive and send object in the format below:

```
{
    "keyid": "value",
    "attr": {
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2",
        "attr3": "value3",
        "attr4": "value4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Good question, although it will probably be closed as "too broad".

In general, the back-end is responsible for persisting data, and performing business logic, preparing and accepting packets of data going to and from the front-end, with the ideal being that the front-end can limit itself to its role, which is primarily to display the data, manage navigation, and handle user interaction, doing whatever pre-processing and manipulation is necessary to accomplish those things.

If the back-end "does not do enough", then you see the front-end needing to make too many data requests to acquire the data it needs, doing the equivalent of "joins" to combine and relate the data, and performing business logic. That slows down the front-end and makes it more complex, and spreads business logic across the back-end and front-end.

On the other hand, if the back-end "does too much", and calculates and provides everything down to the point that it need merely be populated into some HTML templates, the result is that it ends up being too dependent on specific front-end design, meaning that changes require making too many modifications to both sides.

**Therefore, one attempts to strike a golden mean.** The back-end should retrieve all the necessary data, relate and manipulate it, and perform the business logic. It provides a set of relatively abstract, yet fleshed-out data objects which the front-end can then prepare and manipulate for the UI. There are no hard-and-fast rules for where to draw the line.

For example, pagination can be considered a "UI" issue, and can be handled easily by most client frameworks, yet if there are hundreds or thousands of objects, performance considerations might dictate handling this on the server. Same for sorting.

Consider the calculation of the total price of items in a shopping cart. The front-end could easily do this kind of business logic, yet there could be rules such as volume discounts or currency conversions which would be best handled on the back-end. Of course, if the calculation is to be done on the server, that requires another round-trip to the server each time an item is added to the cart in order to recalculate the total. Round-trips are relatively cheap, but in some situations again, performance issues might lead one to want to do this on the client in order to avoid the round-trip.

At the end of the day, this is a set of design choices. Of course, it is all too often the case that the back-end API is "frozen" and the front-end people simply have to work with what they are given.

Comment: Thanks, for the response :)  that was quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are two different versions of JSON object for back end and front end. They are same for both. Its difference is only in how you are accessing it and what method you are using to do so.

You can find various implementations of same on http://json.org/

Comment: Hi Umesh, I have updated the question. I hope the example will make my question more clear. thanks for your response.